# I cannot create flutter new project in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I download flutter sdk & set environment variable path. And then vs code install and install flutter and dart sdk in vs code. After successfully, I type flutter –version check if flutter is installed or not. It is ok, it return successfully. I open folder and then choose a preferred location and I create new project flutter create first_app, this take a long time and nothing to come a success result. And also view> command palette. I cannot search on Google and cannot solve this problems.

Comment: Do you get any error after running `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh flutter doctor -v waiting long time nothing to response in terminal

Comment: try to restart the device/terminal

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh restart device/terminal and also delete task manger relate dart file, but nothing to response waiting long time

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54191643/10157127